# onScrollChanged() never fired on Android 4.0

Tags: android, gridview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, onscroll

I have a GridView that shows images from your gallery. When user scrolls the list, details about the image animate in from the left. I implemented this in the class that defines custom layout for the GridView item. It extends **LinearLayout**.

```
OnScrollChangedListener mScrollListener = new OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        if (!getGlobalVisibleRect(r)) {
            resetAnimation();
        } else {
            if (checkBounds()) {
                    showInfo();
            }
            } else {
                    hideInfo();
            }
```

Method *resetAnimation()* resets the animation if it's view is not visible on screen. Method *checkBounds()* compares the Rect got with *getGlobalVisibleRect(r)* and the Rect representing the screen to check if the details View should be shown.

I add the listener in *onFinishInflate()* like this:

```
        getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(mScrollListener);
```

Now the actual issue:
Everything works fine on **API 19, API 18, API 17 and API 13**, tested both on real devices and emulators. ***On API 14 (Android 4.0.1 and 4.0.2) the onScrollChanged() never gets fired, both on physical device and emulator.***
Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `OnScrollChangedListener`, could you try with `OnScrollListener`...

```
    gridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

I don't know why it is not firing in 4.0, but you could try with this...